# Multifinger action using appium on java

Tags: java, ios, multi-touch, appium

I am writing automation for iOS.

In My iOS App, there is a way to display extra options in App.

I am pressing three fingers on one button and enabling it.

How can i do like pressing three fingers on same time on single button in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple tap functions built into driver itself. For what you want, you should use: `driver.tap(3, element, 500);` 3 for 3 fingers, element for the element you wish to tap, and 500 is the duration in milliseconds.

The source of this method is here:

```
public void tap(int fingers, WebElement element, int duration) {
    MultiTouchAction multiTouch = new MultiTouchAction(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < fingers; i++) {
        multiTouch.add(createTap(element, duration));
    }

    multiTouch.perform();
}
```

which I got from here: https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.java

Comment: I have tried driver.tap(3, element, 500);.  Its just highlighted the full text. Not doing clicking with 3 fingers

Comment: try lowering the duration to something like 250. It looks like 500ms is considered a "long" hold so that's why it's highlighting.